# What time do all of the jungle buff camps spawn?

Tags: paragon

Buff camps were recently changed in Paragon from starting a respawn timer when destroyed to an absolute respawn at certain game-times throughout the match regardless of whether or not they were defeated.

I'm still obviously a bit off on the new system because I sometimes miss out on my lane buffs.

What I'm looking for are the spawn times for:

- Gold Buffs
- River Buffs
- Green Buffs
- Raptor Camp
- Prime Guardian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarlen was correct when he posted his answer, but since the big v.42 update, the times have changed.

White jungle minions now spawn at 1:00, and respawn every minute.

Gold buff and river buffs are unchanged. They still respawn at 3:00 and every odd minute after that.

Green buff is also unchanged. It spawns at 1:30, and then 3 minutes after it was last killed.

Raptors now spawn at 7:00, and respawn 5 minutes after being killed.

Orb Prime now spawns at 10:00, and respawns 7 minutes after being killed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Narendur](https://www.reddit.com/user/Narendur)s [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_J9pKPGp1ddmSpNB_jcFhjjq_OPSILDmjdwzqre3i3U/edit#gid=0) (the de facto source for numbers) the times are:

```
Jungle Minions |  CXP |  XP |         HP |       Damage | Spawns   
---------------+------+-----+------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------
White Minions  |   85 |  20 |        480 |   6 (0.5 AS) | 1:20, 2:20, 3:20, etc.   
Gold Buff      |  300 |   ? |        150 |            ? | 3:00, 5:00, 7:00, etc.                           
Green Buff     |  120 |  40 |        850 |  28 (1.5 AS) | First spawn: 1:30. Respawns 180 seconds after kill   
Raptor         |  650 |  50 | Base:  800 |  15 (0.5 AS) | 10:00. Spawns 300 seconds (5 minutes) after all are killed.   
OP Buff        | 1200 | 200 | Base: 8625 | 100 (0.8 AS) | 15:00. Spawns 480 seconds (8 minutes) after kill   
River Minion   |    0 |   0 |        150 |            ? | 3:00, 5:00, 7:00, etc.
```